# Django/Python - where to define a global immutable dictionary

Tags: python, django, global-variables, immutable.js

Using Python with a Django framework, I need to define a dictionary of tuples. These need to be global and referenced across multiple python files within the application. They will be global across all the user threads and completely immutable ie. constants. These values will be displayed on the pages and printed in reports.
I want to know where is the best place to define these dictionaries, eg. in the views.py file? Please let me know what is the best practice. Thanks so much!

Comment: Do they relate in any way to a particular model? Could you elaborate on what these variables are? Thanks

Comment: Yes, related.
The best analogy is a raffle. I have a list of raffle tickets numbers (the immutable dictionary). Ticket 1 (key) has number 8967876 (value), ticket 2 has number 3546546, ticket 3 has number 0292648, etc. As an organization (user) sells these raffle tickets to customers, each customer model record will include which ticket number they purchased along with customer name, address, etc.   The next organization (user) will reference the same raffle ticket number list and load there own customer table. 
The raffle ticket number list need never change (immutable). I hope that helps.

Comment: Btw, I have two ways of doing this. Throughout the application, I can reference the ticket table with a foreign key in the customer record, or once a customer buys the ticket, I can copy the raffle number directly to his customer record. That's another dicussion however. Either way, I still need the immutable ticket file. I could also make it a model itself other than a dictionary. Soooo many choices.

Comment: I have two suggestions. If the ticket numbers records could increase over time (Maybe ticket 4 and you want to save them relative to a particular ticket, then I would suggest creating a model and foreign key relationship to the ticket model. If not, then you can create a `TICKET_NUMBER_CHOICES = (('Ticket 1','8967876'),('Ticket 2','3546546'),[...])` variable within the model definition  which can be called throughout the code like so: `TicketModel.TICKET_NUMBER_CHOICES`.

Comment: You can see example uses here of *choices* here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices. These do not have to necessarily have to be used in the model fields and allow you to relate the information to the particular model.

Comment: Hi Lewis, This is perfect! Thanks so much. I just gave an example of 3 tickets. There are actually hundreds but will never change, ever. I'm going to use your example above of the tuples list variable within the models file. I'm not sure what you meant by creating the variable in the model definition. Did you just mean withn the models.py file or something more? Please let me know and thanks again.

Comment: By convention it would be recommended to utilize a django model to store the ticket number information even if it may not change (It's neater and better organised). And yes, inside the **models.py** but also inside where your ticket model is defined. Like after `def Ticket(models.Model):`

Comment: Thanks for your advise Lewis, greatly appreciated!